# Raven DB Query on Collections in separate documents

Tags: ravendb

I have a scenario analogous to the following:

Imagine I have three classes

```
public class User
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
}

public class FollowableUser
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> FollowingUserIds {get;set;}
}

public class Event
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> TaggedFollowableUsers {get;set;
}
```

What I'd like to do is be able to query by the Id of the User and have all the Events (or at least the Event Ids) returned.

*edit*
I tried this, but wasn't sure where to go in the reduce part:

```
 AddMap<Event>(events => from evt in events
                                     from fUser in evt.TaggedFollowableUsers 
                                     select new 
                                                {
                                                    FUserId = fUser,
                                                    EventId = evt.Id,
                                                    UserId = (string)null
                                                });

        AddMap<FollowableUser>(fUsers => from fUser in fUsers
                                  from followingUser in child.FollowedingUserIds
                                  select new
                                             {
                                                 FUserId = fUser.Id,
                                                 EventId = (string) null,
                                                 UserId = followingUser
                                             });
        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.FUserId
                            into g
                            select new
                                       {
                                           FUserId= g.Key,
                                           EventId = g.Select(x => x.EventId) // not sure what to do from here
                                       };
```

Is this possible to do with a single queryable index or am I going to need to make multiple calls?

Thanks,

Matt